# Reset the sps on symbol sync block GNU Radio

Tags: rtl-sdr, gnuradio

I'm using symbol sync block (symbol_sync_ff) on my project and i use many different sps values that i need reset on runtime.

I'm trying to reset sending clock_est tag. Is this the right way to reset the sps value?

```
key = pmt.intern("clock_est")
value = pmt.to_pmt((0.0, 45.0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: increase the max deviation value parameter in the block, because the sps range that the block allows is the nominal value +- the user specified allowed deviation.

Answer (score 1):

From `gr-digital/lib/symbol_sync_ff_impl.cc`:

```
// got a clock_est tag
timing_offset = static_cast<float>(
                   pmt::to_double(pmt::tuple_ref(t->value, 0)));
clock_period = static_cast<float>(
                   pmt::to_double(pmt::tuple_ref(t->value, 1)));
```

So, if you want to set the timing offset to 0 and the clock period to 45, then, yep, that's the correct code.

Because I think there will be future visitors to this question: Generally, the documentation can be found under https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1symbol__sync__ff.html

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're telling me.